# Multiplication of two Pauli string

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, mp.mathematical-physics, qa.quantum-algebra, matrix-analysis

Given a Pauli string $P_i  \in \{ I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n} $

Example: $P_0 = XXYIZ = X \otimes X \otimes Y \otimes I \otimes Z $.

Here $I,X,Y,Z$ are Pauli matrices defined explicitly as:
$$
I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} \hspace{1cm} Z = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

**How would you multiply $P_i \cdot P_j$?**

Actually, the question is more about **how to determine the phase factor** rather because one can get the matrix structure by inspecting the Pauli string. That is, suppose you are considering $P_1 = YXZ $ and $P_2 = XZZ $ then

$$ P_1 \cdot P_2 = k\bigg[ (Y\cdot X) \otimes (X \cdot Z) \otimes(Z\cdot Z)\bigg]= k\bigg[ZYI\bigg] $$

using the fact that $YX = -iZ, \ \ XZ = iY, \ \ ZZ = I $. In this case, to get the **right answer, which is** $P_1 \cdot P_2 = (YXZ) \cdot (XZZ) = -ZYI $, we need to pick $k = -1$.

Now, if we instead define $P_3 = XYZ$ and $P_4 = YZZ$ then

$$P_3 \cdot P_4 = k\bigg[ (X \cdot Y) \otimes (Y \cdot Z) \otimes(Z \cdot Z)\bigg]= k\bigg[-ZXI\bigg] $$
using the fact that $X\cdot Y = iZ$, $Y \cdot Z = iX$, and $Z \cdot Z = I$. Hence, to get the **right answer, which is**  $P_3 \cdot P_4 = -ZXI$, we need to pick $k = 1$.

In some cases, the coefficient will be imaginary, for instance $(XXY)\cdot (YIY) = i ZXI$, however I do not care about such term.

---

To give a more bigger picture of what I am doing: I am trying calculate the matrix $H^2$ given that $H$ is a real Hermitian matrix with $H$ being able to decomposed in polynomial number of Pauli strings. That is,
$$ H = \sum_i \alpha_i P_i \hspace{1 cm} P_i \in \{ I,X,Y,Z\}^{\otimes n}, \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: Why do you need the $k$ facto at all? To me at least it's not clear what properties you want it to satisfy. Do you wish to construct an alternative to the usual matrix product such that the product of two Pauli strings is always itself a Pauli string (without extra scalar factors)?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine First, thank you for reading through my question. The factor $k$ is needed to correctly determine the product of two Pauli strings. For instance,  $(X \otimes X \otimes Z) \cdot (X \otimes Y \otimes X) = -I \otimes Z \otimes Y  $ you don't really get that when you do $(X \otimes X \otimes Z) \cdot (X \otimes Y \otimes X) = (X \cdot X) \otimes (X \cdot Y) \otimes (Z \cdot X) = (I) \otimes (iZ) \otimes (-iY) = IZY $. Therefore, the two are offset by a phase factor $k$. By making $k = -1$ here, we would get the correct answer.

Comment: The reason to try to do these matrix multiplication by keeping them in term of Pauli string is to save a lot of memory since you never need to reconstruct the $2^n \times 2^n$ matrix. Remember that I want to calculate $H^2$ matrix where $H$ is composed of linear combination of Pauli strings. If each Pauli string has length $50$ then that would be $2^{50} \times 2^{50}$ matrix. So It would be great if I can just look at the multiplication of two pauli string and determine what the product is. This would only need $O(n^2)$ number of terms. In fact, less because we know $H$ is real Hermitian.

Comment: you don't need to reconstruct the $2^n\times 2^n$ matrix if you keep track of the Pauli matrix multiplication rules $\sigma_\alpha\sigma_\alpha=I$, $\sigma_\alpha\sigma_{\alpha+1}=i\sigma_{\alpha+2}$ for $\alpha\in\{1,2,3\}$ mod 3.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Yeah. That is true. In away, that is the property that I am using as well to get the structure of the product of two Pauli string.

Comment: @KAJ226 There's still something unstated in your question, namely what "the correct" product of Pauli strings means for you. The product that you say is "incorrect" is just the normal matrix product applied to tensor factorized matrices (see the "mixed product property" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations)). So what is the meaning of your "correct" product?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I realized the first example I gave was incorrect so I replaced with a different one. I also edited the question so it makes more sense. Thanks for being patience with me! What I mean "correct" here is the actual matrix multiplication of the two Pauli string, not by doing "mixed product property". As I have shown, by doing it that way leads to wrong phase factor for higher dimension. When you have Pauli string of length 2, it is not a problem. But as you moved up in dimension, there is a $\pm 1$ phase factor problem.

Comment: @KAJ226 In your first example, actually $XZ=-iY$ making the coefficient $k=1$, meaning that there is no difference between the products. In general, the "mixed product property" holds for tensor product strings of any length (associativity of tensor product + induction). Either you are just making computational mistakes in your examples, or it is still not clear what you mean by the "correct" product.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I am feeling like the biggest idiot right now... somehow I messed up my scratch work and thought I found something strange. I want to say thank you for your patience and not call me out for my stupidity.